# PHP code for writing in new line

Tags: php, text, smarty, line

```
$smarty->assign('buttonText', $this->l('CREDIT CARD | DEBIT CARD | NETBANKING  NO Extra Charges '));
```

I want this code to be modified such that " No Extra Charges " is on a new line and not on same line

Current Output

```
CREDIT CARD | DEBIT CARD | NETBANKING  NO Extra Charges
```

Expected output

```
CREDIT CARD | DEBIT CARD | NETBANKING  
NO Extra Charges
```

This is written in PHP. The whole code is

```
public function hookPayment($params)
{
    if (!$this->active)
        return;

    global $smarty;

    $smarty->assign('buttonText', $this->l('CREDIT CARD | DEBIT CARD | NETBANKING  NO Extra Charges '));

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payment.tpl');
}
```

Comment: What problem specifically are you having with this task? Please update the question with that information. (Relating to your conversation under the existing answer, we generally discourage asking for external contact details, since this gives the appearance of wanting a free private support channel. It is generally best to just ask a clear question that someone can answer directly, rather than needing to do extensive debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put break line `<br>` into smarty variable? As I know Smarty it should work.

```
$smarty->assign('buttonText', $this->l('CREDIT CARD | DEBIT CARD | NETBANKING<br>NO Extra Charges '));
```

Comment: I already tried that , Didn't Work. Also Tried "\n" and also tried "\r\n"

Comment: @Arpanjain: What is `$this->l`? It's not default smarty functionality.

Comment: It is working correctly and also displaying everything . But all on the same line.

Comment: @Arpanjain: How it's defined? Or maybe, what's the rendered HTML? Is there `<`, `&lt;`, nothing, or what?

Comment: Can u give me your email id , I will send u the entire file . Which is working correctly.

Comment: @Arpanjain: sorry, no emails. But it seems like there is any `strip_tags` in `$this->l`.

Comment: I dont know what that means . I am not a coder . Sorry. Please can u guide me.

Comment: @Arpanjain: sorry, you have to make something yourself. I asked you _what is $this->l? How it's defined._ You need to find somewhere.

Comment: I have put the entire code , I have edited my question . I hope u will find what it means . As I am not very good at php so I dont know what that means.